# How can I link multiple HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to submit multiple post forms together. In this specific case a filter and a search bar form.

Is it somehow possible to link both so every time one of them gets submitted, it sends the data of the other one too?

Code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <label for="filter">Filter:</label>
    <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter"/>
  </form>
  <br/>
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="SubmitBoth"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two forms and not one?

Comment: @jabaa - only reason might be different `action` endpoints, which OP might have removed for the sake of the question

Comment: It is not possible to have two forms submit on same page instance using browser default process.

Comment: @jabaa the inputs are spread over different parts of the html template, and I'm used to only putting inputs that are close to each other or part of the same group together. but thinking about it you are right, i could just make the whole body a form. I just kinda hoped for a better way. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one form instead of two

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <label for="filter">Filter:</label>
    <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" />
    <br/><br />
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="SubmitBoth" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i didn't really want to put all of the inputs in the same form before, because in my usecase they are spread so far over my html template, that the whole body would need to be a form.  since there doesn't seem to be another solution, will go for this though. thank you.